# How to work with functions and outputs C

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting

I want to enter 4 numbers and display the largest possible number. Can anybody help me with this please? I have tried multiply different approaches, so do not wonder why there are so many libraries. 
Thanks in advance

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>           //pow
    #include <limits.h>         //char max
    #include <ctype.h>          //


int sort_alg(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    char ab[32], ba[32];
    sprintf(ab, "%d%d", *(int*)a, *(int*)b);
    sprintf(ba, "%d%d", *(int*)b, *(int*)a);
    return strcmp(ba, ab);
}

void max_numb(int *a, int len)
{
    int i;
    qsort(a, len, sizeof(int), sort_alg); 
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
  int numbers[4];
  for(int count = 0; count < 4; count++)
  {
      scanf("%d", &numbers[count]);
      printf("%d", numbers);
  }

    max_numb(numbers, sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `printf("%d", numbers);` to `printf("%d\n", numbers[count])`

Comment: regarding this: `printf("%d", numbers);`   `numbers` is an array of 4 integers, so this line should be similar to: `printf( "%d", numbers[ count ] );`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.   In the current scenario, suggest: `if( 1 != scanf("%d", &numbers[count]) ) { fprintf( stderr,  "scanf failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  IE. 4.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or a `#define` statement to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  parameter names like `a` are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to include header files those content is not used.  Suggest removing the `#include` statements for: `math.h', 'limits.h', 'ctype.h'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try some algorithm. It's pretty easy to select just the maximum. You don't have to sort it
Try this:

```
int max(int a[],int len)
{
  int max=a[0];
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    if(max<a[i])
      max=a[i];
  }
  return max;
}
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your query. I answered by the title.

Comment: Sorry, but I am trying to get the largest combined number with any given numbers: 1, 2, 99, 919 would be 9991921.

Answer (score 0):

If printing the largest of the numbers entered is your sole purpose, you can do it without any sorting algorithm. While getting inputs, just use a variable that stores the highest number entered till now, and update the variable if any new value greater than **maxim** is entered

**Code**

```
int main() {
    int numbers[4];
    int maxim = -99999; //any small that you can assue to be minimimum
    for(int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[count]);
        printf("%d ", numbers[count]);
        if(numbers[count] > maxim) {
            maxim = numbers[count];
        }
    }
    printf("\n") ;
    printf("Maximum Value : %d\n", maxim) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I am trying to get the largest combined number with any given numbers: 1, 2, 99, 919 would be 9991921.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the desired functionality.
2. cleanly compiles
3. documents why each header file is included
4. properly checks for errors from system functions

caveat: does not check that all entered numbers are positive ( >= 0 )

Notice that proposed code is failing to prompt the user for each value to input, so the user will be looking at a blank terminal, with a blinking cursor (and wondering what to do)  So the code should be prompting the user for each number.

and now, the proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>          // scanf(), fprintf(), printf(), putchar(), sprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>         // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>         // strcmp()

#define MAX_NUMBERS 4

// prototypes
int sort_alg(const void *a, const void *b);
void max_numb( int Numbers[] );


int main( void )
{
    int numbers[ MAX_NUMBERS ];

    for( int count = 0; count < MAX_NUMBERS; count++ )
    {
        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &numbers[count]) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number: %d failed\n", count+1 );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        printf( " %d", numbers[ count ] );  // leading space for formatting
    }

    max_numb( numbers );

    return 0;
}


int sort_alg(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    char ab[32], ba[32];
    sprintf(ab, "%d%d", *(int*)a, *(int*)b);
    sprintf(ba, "%d%d", *(int*)b, *(int*)a);
    return strcmp(ba, ab);
}


void max_numb( int Numbers[] )
{
    qsort( Numbers, MAX_NUMBERS, sizeof(int), sort_alg);

    putchar( '\n' );  // so output from 'max_numb()' will be on a new line
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++)
        printf( "%d", Numbers[i] );

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

a typical run of the proposed code outputs:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
4321
```